# Couldn't able to access a property of an nested object in React useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'demension')

I got this error while I was trying to access property of my nested object named `specs`

```js
{
  "id": "1",
  "catid": "1",
  "title": "Wipro superstar 260l",
  "ProductCode": "6000",
  "image": "Wiproref.jpg",
  "price": 40000,
  "sku": "8789706",
  "description": " chillls ap sdas \n\n asad sjb sn flkadslk fl,iuhsiofaoo asbk jasf0",
  "specs": {
    "demension": "787 x 56453 ",
    "capacity": "309 liters"
  },
  "features": [
    "eafqwfew af sdzz gsdf ",
    "A sf q fad a sfasssss"
  ],
  "stock": 5
}
```

Above is a response which I got from json-server and I am updating this response object to my React state.

Like this with `setProducts(reponseObject)`:

```js
const {productId} = useParams();
  const [product,setProducts] = React.useState({ errMessage: '', Data:{}} ) 

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchIt = async () =>{
      const responseObject = await ProductFetcherById(productId);
      setProducts(responseObject);
    }
    fetchIt()
  },[productId])
```

although i can access all the properties of the `product` state.
excluding child properties of specs

i was trying to access child properties like this :- `product.Data.specs.demension`

```js
<div className='category-product-info-demension'>
  <h3>demensions :-</h3>
  <label>{product.Data.specs.demension}</label>
</div>
```

I can access all other properties like `product.Data.title`, `product.Data.price`, `product.Data.stock`, etc., but error occurs only while accessing child properties.

Any helpful solution and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Do product.Data.title / price / stock have the actual values ? or it just doesn't throw an error ?

Comment: Your data is still loading.  Your jsx should check if potentially "still-loading" data exists yet.  `<label>{product.Data.specs?.demension || "Data not loaded yet"}</label>`

Comment: "_I can access all other properties like `product.Data.title`, `product.Data.price`..._" What about `product.Data.specs`?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions .I found solution `product.Data.specs?.demension || "data not loaded"` used statement like this it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use optional chaining `product.Data.specs?.demension`

useEffect executes after the component completed the render. When the component renders for the first time, it gets undefined for the value of the specs

Comment: Should only require `product.Data.specs?.demension` since `Data` is always defined